# Starting Zabbix Server within docker replaces strings with nothing in config file →

Tags: docker, zabbix

→ or totally ignored strings like name of new DB for testing purposes.

Firstly tries to add something about ~250 to 250 already added hosts and Z-server shutted down. I've restarted it and inside docker logs I saw this:

> `6:20191014:091840.201 using configuration file: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
>   6:20191014:091840.223 current database version (mandatory/optional): 04020000/04020001
>   6:20191014:091840.223 required mandatory version: 04020000
>   6:20191014:091840.484 __mem_malloc: skipped 7 asked 108424 skip_min 304 skip_max 12192
>   6:20191014:091840.484 [file:dbconfig.c,line:94] __zbx_mem_realloc(): out of memory (requested 108424 bytes)
>   6:20191014:091840.484 [file:dbconfig.c,line:94] __zbx_mem_realloc(): please increase CacheSize configuration parameter
>   6:20191014:091840.484 === memory statistics for configuration cache ===`

Solution for those problem was to increase CacheSize in zabbix_server.conf . Okay, that's not a problem and after this Im push a new config to Z-server and restart it... → and z-server stops already after start and logs says the same problem. After reading config in container I saw what string what I corrected to matching my wishes are missing O_o. Strings are deleted.

My config:

```
LogType=console
DBHost=postgres-server
DBName=zabbix_pwd
DBSchema=public
DBUser=zabbix
DBPassword=zabbix
DBPort=5432

StartPollers=5
StartIPMIPollers=5
StartPollersUnreachable=5
SNMPTrapperFile=/var/lib/zabbix/snmptraps/snmptraps.log
StartSNMPTrapper=1

CacheSize=512M
HistoryCacheSize=512M
HistoryIndexCacheSize=512M
TrendCacheSize=512m
ValueCacheSize=256M

AlertScriptsPath=/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts
ExternalScripts=/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts
FpingLocation=/usr/sbin/fping
Fping6Location=/usr/sbin/fping6
SSHKeyLocation=/var/lib/zabbix/ssh_keys
SSLCertLocation=/var/lib/zabbix/ssl/certs/
SSLKeyLocation=/var/lib/zabbix/ssl/keys/
SSLCALocation=/var/lib/zabbix/ssl/ssl_ca/
LoadModulePath=/var/lib/zabbix/modules/
```

And what I've getting after starting z-server:

```
LogType=console
DBHost=postgres-server
DBName=zabbix_pwd
DBSchema=public
DBUser=zabbix
DBPassword=zabbix
DBPort=5432

SNMPTrapperFile=/var/lib/zabbix/snmptraps/snmptraps.log

StartSNMPTrapper=1


AlertScriptsPath=/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts
ExternalScripts=/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts
FpingLocation=/usr/sbin/fping
Fping6Location=/usr/sbin/fping6
SSHKeyLocation=/var/lib/zabbix/ssh_keys
SSLCertLocation=/var/lib/zabbix/ssl/certs/
SSLKeyLocation=/var/lib/zabbix/ssl/keys/
SSLCALocation=/var/lib/zabbix/ssl/ssl_ca/
LoadModulePath=/var/lib/zabbix/modules/
```

**Any suggestions** *to how-to rule the world and don't be captured by doctors* **?**

Answer (score 0):

With docker you need to send conf parameters in the docker-compose.yml file, or in your docker run command using the -e :

For example from my docker yml file:

```
    zabbix-server:
         image: zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql:ubuntu-4.2.6
         environment:
                    ZBX_MAXHOUSEKEEPERDELETE: 5000
                    ZBX_STARTPOLLERS: 15
                    ZBX_CACHESIZE: 8M
                    ZBX_STARTDBSYNCERS: 4
                    ZBX_HISTORYCACHESIZE: 16M
                    ZBX_TRENDCACHESIZE: 4M
                    ZBX_VALUECACHESIZE: 8M
                    ZBX_LOGSLOWQUERIES: 3000
```

Another way to work with zabbix:
https://hub.docker.com/r/monitoringartist/zabbix-3.0-xxl/

Comment: I found a workaround for my problem: using this param - Include=/my/way/zb.conf
So Ive created zb.conf with my params and put it in folder ↑.
And thats help me ;-)
Thanks for the answer.